# Unable to handle volley response as JsonObject

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have an API which returns the response like "**[{"VideoReferenceURL":"x0DE_VDEEAw"}]**"

I need to capture the value of "VideoReferenceURL" variable into a string variable "videoURL"

But when i use below code, the method is not getting into onResponse.

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                requestUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                try {
                    String videoURL = response.getString("VideoReferenceURL");
                    Log.d("VideoURL",videoURL);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                progressDialog.hide();
                Log.d("myerror","I got some error");
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.d("myerror1",error.getMessage());
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String credentials = Constants.WS_Username+":"+Constants.WS_Password;
                String auth = "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(_context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

When i use above with StringRequest, i am getting into onResponse, but **response** is having entire String rather than JSON. I need to write custom string logic to extra the required value.

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                Log.d("VideoURL",response);
            }
        }
```

Tried below to handle as JSON, but it is still not getting into onResponse method

```
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("VideoURL",object.getString("VideoReferenceURL"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
```

Can someone tell me what i am missing here?

Comment: The value you receive from the API is not a JSON Object, instead it is a JSON Array with one element which in turn is a JSON Object.

Comment: @Henry thanks for your inputs. I missed that part and after handling as Array, it is working fine.